# Why are polarized capacitors are treated as non polarized in Clamping circuits?

Tags: power-electronics, electrolytic-capacitor

This semester we studied clamping circuits, but there's rather strange happened when the professor was explaining the working of the circuit, he treated polarized caps as if they were non-polarized. I thought to myself may be he was wrong about that so I searched the internet and found a video explaining it in the same way.

Here's the link to the lecture:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_L71uXbwhG0dC1XaklTZnRaUUU

Here's the link t the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LA7c7jenkd0

So what am I missig here?

Comment: The caps are polarized and correctly. You need to think a bit more about the voltages in the clamping circuits.

Comment: What do you mean by think a bit about applied voltages? I don't understand 

Comment: The link to the lectures is not working (404).

Comment: I will Search for an alternative link.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the polarity of the cap lead and the polarity of the voltage out relative to ground.

Polarity is certainly important and not ignored here.

In most cases up to 10% or rated voltage may be applied in reverse.

Comment: So what is the advantage of this polarization, if it is going to act like a non-polarized under certain voltages?

Comment: It is a current breakdown effect where the threshold in reverse has a limited safe potential before the insulating dielectric turns into a lossy conductor that is self-destructive.

Comment: So I get "why" it is not damaged but why do we use it in the first place? Will it charge and discharge one way only?

Comment: Correct Polarized Caps are used for applications which prevent reverse polarity voltage and are lower cost (in large values) otherwise Non-polarized caps must be used

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/nyj57rt  sim plot

Comment: i.e. your question assumes non-polar cap but here a polarized cap may be used.